# Test to page for full page cache

Tags: full-page-cache, enterprise-1.13

How can I test a page to make sure it is fully cached in EE1.13?

We are having some back and forth and the host is saying that the page may not even be cached.

Comment: did you get anywhere with this?

Comment: No I gave up with this client

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Z-Ray you can totally see if pages are getting into the full page cache. You can even trace down into the functions that run as it generates the caches.

Here is a shot of z-ray in action, showing the cache being built:
[image: Magento FPC Build Process]

Now compare this to the following shot, where you can see that a lot of the functionality of z-ray is missing, but this is because the Mage::run() and Mage::app() calls have completely been cached, and everything is firing out of FPC.
[image: Magento FPC Cache Response]